# Логические и арифметические операции в Java

Tags: операторы, java

Добрый день. Изучаю Java и натолкнулся на два таких вопроса:

```
1. int x = 5;      
   x = ++x;   
   System.out.println( x ); // prints 6  
   x = x++;     
   System.out.println( x ); // prints 6!  
   x = ++x + x++;   
   System.out.println( x ); // prints 14!

2. x=0
   System.out.println("x++==x"); 
   //выводит false

   x=0
   System.out.println("x==x++"); 
   //выводит true
```

Собственно вопросы заключались в том, что выведут эти программы. И я не понял, почему в первом примере, после второй операции инкремента результат все равно остается 6 ? И далее строчка, результат которой тоже мне не понятен. Почему именно 14 ? В следующем примере я не понимаю, почему в первом примере и во втором примере идет аналогичное сравнение, но при этом ответы разные. Заранее Спасибо.

Comment: простите а где вы увидели "декремент"?? я вижу только инкремент в префиксной и постфиксной записи...

Comment: извините , описался . исправил.

Comment: у меня вопрос, вы знаете что такое префиксная и постфиксная запись и принцип их работы?

Comment: не нужно писать такой код. А в некоторых языках (С/С++) это ещё и очень неоднозначный код, который часто зависит от положения Луны относительно Венеры.

Comment: нет , как видите не знаю. вот и спрашиваю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для того чтобы понять, представьте себе некую область памяти куда будет записываться значение, я обозначу её как [*], оно используется для временного хранения.

- **`//число//`** означает порядок
     выполнения
- **`//(текст)`** означает значение
     переменных после выполнения строчки
     кода

ну а теперь описание:

```
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        x = ++x;//ниже описан порядок действия
                //1//++x        //(x равен 6)
                //2//x=x        //(x равен 6)
        System.out.println( x ); // prints 6
        x = x++;
                //1//[*]=x      //(x равен 6,[*] равен 6)
                //2//x++        //(x равен 7,[*] равен 6)
                //3//x=[*]      //(x равен 6,[*] равен 6)
        System.out.println( x ); // prints 6!
        x = ++x + x++;
                //1//++x        //(x равен 7)
                //2//[*]=x+x    //(x равен 7,[*] равен 14)
                //3//x++        //(x равен 8,[*] равен 14)
                //4//x=[*]      //(x равен 14,[*] равен 14)
        System.out.println( x ); // prints 14!

        /* ниже символом ' буду помечать левый X */
        x=0;
        System.out.println(x++==x);
                //1//[*]='x     //(x равен 0,[*] равен 0)
                //2//'x++       //(x равен 1,[*] равен 0)
                //3//[*]=x      //(x равен 1,[*] равен 0)
        //выводит false

        x=0;
        System.out.println(x==x++);
                //1//'x         //(x равен 0)
                //2//[*]=x      //(x равен 0,[*] равен 0)
                //3//x++        //(x равен 1,[*] равен 0)
                //4//x=[*]      //(x равен 0,[*] равен 0)
        //выводит true
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Именно то объяснение , которое хотел увидеть, что бы понять по какому именно принципу выполняются операции сравнения и инкремента

Comment: учтите один важный момент:

насколько я помню в java всегда арифметика идёт строго "слева на право" потому можно точно предсказать поведение

но как верно подметил KoVadim в комментарии выше в C\C++ это UB, так как в разных компиляторах такое будет считаться по разному (где слева на права, а где наоборот)

Comment: Скажите , а где можно прочитать про подобные примеры ?

Comment: вообще про префикс, постфикс, указатели, операторы взятия адреса и разыменования адреса в языке C\C++ есть хорошая статься на хабре.

но у меня её в "избранном" нету и попытки поиска ни к чему не привели.

по java я такого не видел...



вообще в той статье на хабре объяснялось как читать вот такой изврат "`*(&***X+1)-100500`"

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите префиксную и постфиксную виды инкремента. Если просто, то в первом случае вы сначала увеличиваете x, а потом только присваиваете результат. Во втором случае вы сначала берете значение x и присваиваете, а потом только увеличиваете правый x, что не приводит к изменениям левого операнда.
Следующий пример тоже самое - слева увеличивается на 1, а справа нет, поэтому 6+1 + 7 = 14
В третьем примере, собсно как и во втором, уже вкрадывается приоритет выполнения слева-направо (смотреть таблицу приоритетов операций)

Comment: а можете объяснить принцип приоритета выполнения. то есть как именно происходят подобные сравнения ?

Answer (score 0):

я пользуюсь простым правилом:

`int x = 5;  
x = ++x;   // прибавить и затем взять - взяли 5+1=6, 6 сохранили
x = x++;   // взять затем прибавить - взяли 6, прибавили и сохранили 7`